# Jackpot with guessing the word PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

So I made this application for a local radiostation which is basically a word guessing game with a Jackpot. When a user enters the page $bericht needs to show how high the Jackpot is. The jackpot needs to increase by 5 and $bericht needs to update every time someone miss guessed the word and the user wins the Jackpot if they guessed it right and it will show how much they won in $bericht. But every time I answer it wrong, it still say's that I guessed it right. This needs to be done using PDO and PHP.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once "manager.php";

    $manager = new funtionHandler();

    $database = $manager->getBCWaarde();

    $bcDatabase = $database->bc;

    $message= "De pot ligt nu op&nbsp;" . $bcDatabase . "BC!";

    if ($_POST) {
        $checkAnswer= $manager->getAntwoordByInput($_POST["antwoord"]);

        $correctAnswer= isset($checkAnswer);

        if ($correctAnswer) {
            $message= "Het antwoord is goed!&nbsp; Jij wint&nbsp;" . $bcDatabase . "BC!";

            $bcCount = 0;

            $manager->updateBCWaarde($bcCount);
        }else{
            $bcCount = $bcDatabase += 5;

            $message= "Het antwoord is fout!&nbsp; De pot ligt nu op&nbsp;" . $bcCount . "BC!";

            $manager->updateBCWaarde($bcCount);
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my PHP Functionmanager:

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

class funtionHandler{
    public function getAntwoordByInput($aInput) {            
        global $conn;

        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hetgeluid WHERE antwoord LIKE '?';");

        $statement->bindValue(1, $aInput);

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }

    public function getBCWaarde() {            
        global $conn;

        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT bc FROM hetgeluid");

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }

    public function updateBCWaarde($bcWaarde) {            
        global $conn;

        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE hetgeluid SET bc = ? WHERE id = 1");

        $statement->bindValue(1, $bcWaarde);

        $statement->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
  <form method="post" action="">
     <textarea required type="text" style="height:100px; width:100%;" class="customField" cols="40" rows="5" style="resize: none;" name="antwoord"></textarea><br /><br />
     <input type="submit" class="customSuccessButton" value="Verstuur"/>                                  
   </form>
   <br />
   <?php echo $message; ?>
```

Comment: Generally it's recommended to only use English words for variables to make sure you don't end up with half assed words. And when you ask for help it's much easier to just copy paste instead of having to translate all your variables.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you check whether the answer is correct seems to be the problem here.

```
$checkAntwoord = $manager->getAntwoordByInput($_POST["antwoord"]);
```

The `getAntwoordByInput` method returns the result of `$statement->fetchObject()`, which returns the next row as object, or `false` if there is none.

```
$goedAntwoord = isset($checkAntwoord);
```

The [isset](http://php.net/isset) function checks whether a variable exists and is not `null`.

The variable `$checkAntwoord` always exists. If the answer is correct it'll be of type `object`, if not it'll be a `boolean` (`false`). Either way, it's not `null`. Therefore your condition will always be true.

```
if ($goedAntwoord) {
```

You could use the [empty](http://php.net/empty) function instead. For example:

```
$goedAntwoord = !empty($checkAntwoord);
if ($goedAntwoord) {
```